# Are Java products deployed in byte-code stage?

Tags: java, jvm

I have learnt that java programs are converted into byte-code after compiling and they are again converted into native code at executing stage by **JVM**.

I also learnt that java programs can be executing slower than other programs from languages without intermediate execution stage( because java byte-code need to be converted into native code at each execution). There are some advantages like platform independent programming.

But, what happen when it comes to enterprise level software. There is no need of being platform independent after it has been installed in our computer.

*( they distribute in different methods for each operating systems: ex- .exe setups for windows )*

So are they using some methods to compile their product directly into native code and deploy?

Or are they still build and deploy their products using byte-code files??

Comment: AFAIK there is nothing about an IDE which changes everything you said in the first part of your question (which looks correct, at least to me).  An IDE like IntelliJ just makes it easy to develop and run Java applications, but it does so using the regular `java` and `javac` commands which you would use from the command line.

Comment: C# is also bytecode (MSIL). Consider looking into the directory IntelliJ is installed to and check for ".jar" / ".class"-files

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, i think you misunderstood me or i asked my question wrong. I'm not considering about using IDE to write java programs. I'm asking about deploying huge enterprise level software like IDE. Are they compile it to byte-code somehow and deploy it?

Comment: @tionsys. sorry i thought C# is compiling source code directly into native code.I edited my question. thanx. No '.class' files. So, are they compile them to native code before deploying?

Comment: No problem; are there any .jar-files? If not, it's native code.

Comment: thnx for your support. @tionsys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Java is Platform independent.**

means whenever, a program is written in JAVA, it will run on any OS platform.

1. a JAVA program get compiled with javac command.
2. The result of the JAVA compiler is the .class file or the bytecode and not the machine native code (unlike C compiler).
3. The bytecode generated is a non-executable code and needs an interpreter to execute on a machine. This interpreter is the JVM and thus the Bytecode is executed by the JVM.

And finally program runs to give the desired output.

**JVM is platform dependent**

In Java, the main point here is that the JVM depends on the operating system. Each OS have there own JVM which installs along with Jdk.

1. In the case of Java, it is the magic of Bytecode that makes it platform independent.
2. This adds to an important feature in the JAVA language termed as **portability**. Every system has its own JVM which gets installed automatically when the jdk software is installed. For every operating system separate JVM is available which is capable to read the .class file or byte code.
3. Different JVM is designed for different OS and byte code is able to run on different OS.

*The **important answer of the question is** there is nothing comes with the IDE (InteliJ, Eclipse etc). All IDE compile the Java code with **javac** and run with **java** command*

Comment: Thanx for the information. But im asking about deployment of enterprise level softwares like IDEs or something other. I just took InteliJ IDE as an example. Are they build them as byte-code or not?

Comment: So, when it convert into native code??when i install them, or each time i runs the program??

Comment: When you install, all required class files and bytecodes are get extracted and copied to a location in your hard drive. But when you run the program then it actually run the bytecodes on JVM.